# AI Gym environment: no module found error despite all steps correct

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, openai-gym

I am very sure that I followed the correct steps to register my custom environment in the AI Gym. But I face a problem when **one __ init__.py file is not recognizing a folder and gives no module found error.**  I use Anaconda Jupyterlab through OneDrive so that it is synced and I work from any device.

The path is C-> Users-> myname->OneDrive-> My_code->gym_mycode

1. gym_mycode--> envs folder and a first __ init__.py file
2. Inside envs-->another second __ init__.py, custom_env, and some other files

Contents of my first __ init__ are:

```
from gym.envs.registration import register
register(id="PyABCD-v0", entry_point="gym_mycode.envs:CustomEnv_class")
```

Contents of my second __ init__ inside the envs folder are:

```
from gym_mycode.envs.custom_env import CustomEnv_class
```

This second one gives me the error  No module named 'gym_mycode'. How is it possible that it is not recognizing the gym_mycode folder? Is it because I am operating this whole thing inside OneDrive and not some Anaconda specific folder?

I run the first init first and then the second init inside the envs. Hope this order of running is correct.

**Edit** As asked, below is the current dir and traceback.

`os.getcwd()` is `C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\My_code\gym_mycode\envs`

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [23], in <cell line: 6>()
      3 import sys
      4 sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\HP\\OneDrive\\My_code\\gym_mycode')
----> 6 from gym_mycode.envs.custom_env import CustomEnv_class

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym_mycode'
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: code may runs in different folder (`current working directory` - check `os.getcwd()`) and then `import` search module `gym_mycode` in different folder. You may need to add folder `/full/path/to/My_code` to `sys.path` before import `gym_mycode`

Comment: @furas Many thanks for your suggestion. It worked. As you said, I added sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\HP\\OneDrive\\My_code') in the second __ init__ inside the envs and then did the from gym_mycode.envs.custom_env import CustomEnv_class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code may runs in different folder (`current working directory` - check `os.getcwd()`) and then `import` search module `gym_mycode` in different folder.

You may need to add folder `/full/path/to/My_code` to `sys.path` before `import gym_mycode`

Common mistake is to add path to file but it has to be path to folder.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/full/path/to/My_code")      # add at the end of list
#sys.path.insert(0, "/full/path/to/My_code")  # add at the beginning of list

import gym_mycode
```